# Ionic : Value in input field will not display with ngControl

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am using Ionic framework 4 . I want to set a default value in input tag .

here is my code :

in .ts file

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router, private sqlite: SQLite, private sqliteDbCopy: SqliteDbCopy) {

  this.PhNumber = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('number');

}
```

in html:

```
     <ion-input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="ph_number" value={{PhNumber}}></ion-input>
  <ion-button  size="small" type="submit"  expand="block" (click)="saveChat()">Send Your Message</ion-button>
```

But don't know why the value is not displaying in the text field.
If I remove the ngModel like :

```
 <ion-input type="text"   value={{PhNumber}} ></ion-input>
  <ion-button  size="small" type="submit"  expand="block" (click)="saveChat()">Send Your Message</ion-button>
```

the value is displaying .
I am new in Ionic please help . How to display the value with ngModel . without ngModel how can I save data to database.

My save to database function :

```
msg='';ph_number ='';

saveChat(){

        var status='Outgoing';

        this.sqlite.create({
          name: 'chat_app.db',
          location: 'default'
        }).then( (db: SQLiteObject) => {

          db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat_list_details(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ph_number VARCHAR(32),status VARCHAR(32),msg TEXT)', [])
          .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
          .catch(e => console.log(e));

          db.executeSql(" INSERT INTO chat_list_details (ph_number,status,msg) VALUES (?,?,?) ", [ this.ph_number,status,this.msg ] ).then(() => console.log('value inserted in SQL'))
          .catch(e => console.log(e));

})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing `ph_number`? It works when I try your code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-eeataf

Answer (score 0):

> Here is Working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-xoe7uk?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**.html**

```
<ion-card>
        <ion-input type='ph_number' [(ngModel)]='ph_number'></ion-input>
</ion-card>
```

**.ts**

```
ph_number: number =80;
```

Comment: this.PhNumber = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('number');  hey this.PhNumber assigning values check that ?

Comment: how to display the value its not displayed

Comment: check console.log(this.PhNumber) inside constructor

Comment: remove value={{PhNumber}} section

Comment: then how can i save data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196709/discussion-between-orbit-and-ajay-krishna-dutta).

Answer (score -1):

try this"" and it will work,
how ever you are binding the value that you are getting already.
so by using that variable in ngModel can change the value of that variable